# What are dangling edges in a Nebula Graph?

Tags: nebula-graph

I executed a statement in NebulaGraph database.

```
nebula> CREATE EDGE IF NOT EXISTS e1();                 
nebula> INSERT EDGE e1 () VALUES "10"->"11":();
```

But actually I didn't insert vertex 10 and 11.

So this is dangling edges? How can I use this in my scenario?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer my explanation. A dangling edge is an edge that only connects to a single vertex and only one part of the edge connects to the vertex.

Dangling edges may appear in NebulaGraph 3.3.0 as the design. And there is no MERGE statements of openCypher. The guarantee for dangling edges depends entirely on the application level.

Comment: "_You can refer this_" Refer to what? Is the following sentence a quote from documentation? If so, link to the documentation and put doublequotes around the sentence.